# Page fires a page_load after Server.Transfer()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project building both server and client for a mock trade system (University project). As a part of the debug process I found that the page reloads just after a button is pressed that calls the Server.transfer(). I read a lot about this problem when using Response.Redirect() but I found little information about that.

How can I force the page not to reload when transferring?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the IsPostBack property on the Page_load Function.

Still can`t understand why this is happenning but it fixed the extra reload when using the Server.Transfer